# Is there an addon or a trick to prevent objects from being placed inside of each other?

Tags: modeling, add-on

I was trying to make a big cluster of balloons but it toke to much time to place every balloon in a random position without them intercepting. Is there anyting that can prevent this, like an addon that prevents objects or vertex groups of objects from intercepting?

Comment: Do you mean in the final animation, or while you're editing the scene?  I don't think there is a limit distance constraint for groups. I agree with @HybridLizard, simulation will be the way to go, if it's a large group of balloons. Alternatively, you could use balloon as particle, and set the particles to no-intersect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rigid Body simulation, maybe combined with some forces to distribute balloons. That may take some time and experiments to make it right.

[image: Quick example of several minutes setup]

You can automate that by mass copying rigid body properties from one balloon to others. Please check Blender docs to know more about Rigid Bodies and Force Fields.

You can automate your work by writing small python script. Please note that a lot of commands you need can be taken from the console.

[image: Plane added and respective command are highlighted in red]

Depending on how "big" number of balloons you want using a particle system for instancing balloons can be quite good solution. To make balloons more diverse, there can be made several versions of them and grouped. Then you just need to use that group for instancing and adjust settings like number, size variation, etc. Unfortunately Blender currently does not directly support Rigid Bodies for Particle System instances so they need to be converted to objects first.